# How can I remove duplicate parts of a string, within a column and sort the values

Tags: python, pandas, string, sorting, duplicates

I have a dataframe like this (assuming one column):

```
column
[A,C,B,A]
[HELLO,HELLO,ha]
[test/1, test/1, test2]
```

The type of the column above is:
dtype('O')

I would like to remove the duplicates here, resulting in:

```
column
[A,C,B]                  # - A
[HELLO, ha]               # removing 1 hello
[test/1, test2]  # removing 1 test/1
```

Then, I would like to sort the data

```
column
[A,B,C]                  
[ha, HELLO]             
[test2, test/1]  # assuming that number comes before /
```

I am struggling getting this done in a proper way. Hope anyone has nice ideas (would it make sense to transform to small lists?)

Comment: `object` is no so meaningful, it would be lists, strings… what is the output of `df.to_dict('list')`? Also, the sorting logic is not conventional (upper case usually sorts before lowercase), can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have **lists** in the column, use a list comprehension.

If you want to maintain order:

```
df['column_keep_order'] = [list(dict.fromkeys(x)) for x in df['column']]
```

If you want to sort the items:

```
df['column_sorted'] = [sorted(set(x)) for x in df['column']]
```

output:

```
                    column column_keep_order    column_sorted
0             [A, C, B, A]         [A, C, B]        [A, B, C]
1       [HELLO, HELLO, ha]       [HELLO, ha]      [HELLO, ha]
2  [test/1, test/1, test2]   [test/1, test2]  [test/1, test2]
```

reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': [['A','C','B','A'],
                              ['HELLO','HELLO','ha'],
                              ['test/1', 'test/1', 'test2']]})
```

Answer (score 3):

A set is a datatype which is like a list but it only includes unique values. This means that you can convert your list to a set and then back to a list (if you want a list of those unique values).

You would then write something like this:

```
list(set(name_of_the_list))
```

Answer (score 3):

Nested list inside of a dataframe is not a good habits to use, maybe for some really specific problems. I strongly encourage you to read how to stick to [tidy paradigm](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) (I know it's from a R point of view, but it can be easily transcript into python).

Nonetheless, using `Numpy` functions as `unique` and `sort` can do the job for your example, assuming `df` is your dataframe :

### Using a for loop on your dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"col" : 
                   [["A","C","B","A"],
                    ["HELLO","HELLO","ha"],
                    ["test/1", "test/1", "test2"]]})
    
for n, value in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[n, "col"] = np.sort(np.unique(value.loc["col"]))

df
Out[77]: 
               col
0        [A, B, C]
1      [HELLO, ha]
2  [test/1, test2]
```

### Using applymap

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col" : 
                   [["A","C","B","A"],
                    ["HELLO","HELLO","ha"],
                    ["test/1", "test/1", "test2"]]})
    
df2 = df2.applymap(lambda x : np.sort(np.unique(x)))

df2
Out[75]: 
               col
0        [A, B, C]
1      [HELLO, ha]
2  [test/1, test2]
```

Comment: Compare the sort order in your output and in the expected output. It is different.

Comment: Indeed, it depends on how numpy sort string items. A homemade sorting function will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Leverage set.

If already a list

```
df['column2']=[list(set(x)) for x in df.column.to_list()]

       

     column          column2
0             [A, C, B, A]        [A, C, B]
1       [HELLO, HELLO, ha]      [HELLO, ha]
2  [test/1, test/1, test2]  [test2, test/1]
```

otherwise

```
df['column2']=df['column'].str.replace('\]|\[','',regex=True).str.split(',').map(set).map(list)
```

or

```
df['column2']=df['column'].str.replace('\]|\[','',regex=True).apply(lambda x:list(set(x.split(','))))


       

                  column          column2
0             [A, C, B, A]        [A, C, B]
1       [HELLO, HELLO, ha]      [HELLO, ha]
2  [test/1, test/1, test2]  [test2, test/1]
```

Comment: It works, is it also still possible to sort the outcome of the first approach?

Comment: Yap, `df['column2']=[sorted(list(set(x))) for x in df.column.to_list()]`